# Appdomain memory issue

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, appdomain

I have created a small windows service that runs plugins.

Each plugin is a dll that gets loaded into its own seperate `AppDomain` using `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` method and I keep a reference to the `AppDomain`.

Once the plugin completes, I shut down the `AppDomain` that is created for that plugin.  I'm using shadow copy to allow updates to the plugins while they are running in the framework.

It has run for 6 months perfectly untill last week when I decided to put the core functionality of the framework into a seperate dll also and execute that dll in a seperate `AppDomain`.

The way it works right now is:

1. Windows service comes up.
2. The core dll is loaded and executed using `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` which in turn is responsible for running the plugins in their own seperate `AppDomain`

I have couple of different locations for assemblies:

- Bin Folder (Bin of the windows service holds only dlls used by the service)
- Core DLLs Folder (Core dlls get dropped in here)
- References Folder (any references get dropped in here)
- Plugins Folder (plugins get dropped in here)

I resolve any unfound dlls by hooking up to each the `OnAssemblyResolve` event on the `AppDomain`.  This allows dlls to be loaded from over the network.

Now the problem is the windows service ran for one day and the memory went as high as 1.5G. I created a dump of the memory and seems like loaded modules are only 100MB of the whole 1.5G so I dont know where all this memory is going to.

Using debugging I saw an alert for heap fragmentation but I have no idea where I should start to diagnose the issue. Usually when the framework runs for a day it consumed something like 100M.

Also this is not related to the plugins either; when I rolled back my changes to the framework the memroy usage became normal as before. When I create the `AppDomain` for plugins, I switch the basePath and the bin path of the `AppDomain` to CORE and References folders that have most of the dlls in there in hope that the assembly resolve gets called less often.

I looked at fusion logs and also read a little bit more about load contexts like default, from, and none but im not sure if thats the right path to take.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that registering to the `AssemblyResolve` attribute new?

Comment: Is it possible to post some code to give us some more information?

Comment: Why are you not using the classes in the [`System.AddIn` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020.aspx)?  There's absolutely *no* reason to write this kind of code yourself.

Comment: Yes,resolve assembly part is new.

Comment: Its already late and the project is very coupled with appdomains instead of the system.addins... so no choice right now.

Comment: Bryan,I'm not really sure which part of the code i should post on here?

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading SciNet memory profiler. I did use that tool to diagnose problems with services and it really does help to figure out where the issue is. There is a free evaluation version available.

If you cannot or do not want to install it, you can try to split your plugins in 2 halfs and see if they have the same memory behavior. You can also try with no plugins at all.

Also, Garbage collecting object across App domains seems to be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956792/garbage-collecting-objects-crossing-appdomain-boundary). You might want to investigate.